# ExpandableListView where is the LIstener?

Tags: android, listener, expandablelistview

I have a basic ExpandableListView, reprogrammed using a tutorial:

http://www.tutorialsbuzz.com/2014/07/android-simple-expandable-listview.html

Now what I do not understand:

When I click on a groupItem it expands, showing the children.
WHERE Is the Listener that actually handles this? I cannot find out which method is responsible for this.
Probably a very basic question

Comment: do You mean onGroupClickListener?

Answer (score 1):

[ExpandableListView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html) has [OnChildClickListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener.html) which handles the child view clicks.

**Interface definition for a callback to be invoked when a child in this expandable list has been clicked.**

Comment: as mentioned in your *tutorial* 'clicks on group' you mean "apple, samsung?"

Answer (score 1):

Have you seen these **three Listeners** in your code??? It is in the tutorial as well, I copied these from your tutorial.

```
      //// Child Click Listener
    ExpandList.setOnChildClickListener(new OnChildClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
            return false;
        }
    });

      //// Group expand Listener
    ExpandList.setOnGroupExpandListener(new OnGroupExpandListener() {

        @Override
        public void onGroupExpand(int groupPosition) {

        }
    });

      //// Group Collapse Listener
    ExpandList.setOnGroupCollapseListener(new OnGroupCollapseListener() {

        @Override
        public void onGroupCollapse(int groupPosition) {
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope these are the listeners you are looking for

```
        expandableListView.setOnGroupExpandListener();
        expandableListView.setOnGroupCollapseListener();
        expandableListView.setOnGroupClickListener();
        expandableListView.setOnChildClickListener();
```

Comment: As a matter of fact, I found them and deleted them all except the last one. However, if I click on a group it still expands. So how can that be?

Answer (score 1):

```
exp_list.setOnGroupExpandListener(new OnGroupExpandListener() {

        @Override
        public void onGroupExpand(int groupPosition) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
```